# handling network errors during polling an entity

Tags: entity

[Notebook with a not working draft to solve the problem:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvrrsIGD554eTKZ6TX6p_vThRgb1NdWH/view?usp=sharing) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EvrrsIGD554eTKZ6TX6p_vThRgb1NdWH/view?usp=sharing

Hello,

I use Entity["Isotope",...] to calculate radioactive decay chains. These calculations last up to several days. During this time, I get sometimes network errors because of timeouts:

> `EntityValue::conopen`: Using EntityValue requires internet connectivity. Please check your network connection. You may need to configure your firewall program or set a proxy in the Internet Connectivity tab of the Preferences dialog.

> `EntityValue::nodat`: Unable to download data. Some or all results may be missing.

The output result is: `Missing[RetrievalFailure]`

My internet service provider (isp) does sometimes something, I cannot avoid. As a result I must restart the calculation. To avoid this I want to have some code, that ensures, that the Entity[…] request worked correct with no error. If the error lasts for an hour, that is no problem, if I can avoid to restart a calculation from scratch afer one day! I think, that the following code shows what I am searching:

Without error handling I defined the function ssEntity (ss as first letter means stored):

```
ClearAll@ssEntity;
ssEntity[type$of$entity_String,isotope$name_String][propety_String]:=ssEntity[type$of$entity,isotope$name][propety]=Entity[type$of$entity,isotope$name][propety];
ssEntity["Isotope","Pu236"]["AtomicMass"]
```

gives the correct output

```
Quantity[236.046057964,"AtomicMassUnit"]
```

To manage network errors, I defined

```
ClearAll[sEntity]; counted$polls = 0; 
sEntity[type$of$entity_String, isotope$name_String][
  propety_String] :=(*sEntity[type$of$entity,isotope$name][propety]=*)
 Block[{p, f}, 
  While[MissingQ@(f = 
      Enclose[ConfirmQuiet[
        p = Entity[type$of$entity, isotope$name][propety]], 
       Missing[] &]);(**); Pause[1]; MissingQ@f, counted$polls++; 
   Echo[{f, p, MissingQ@f, counted$polls}]; f]; p];
sEntity["Isotope", "Pu244"]["AtomicMass"]
```

doesn’t do what I want with network connection ore without it.
Kind regards from Peter